# How to include my implementation in cpp file for some header file (nested classes)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I faced a problem while trying to arrange my project files C++

simply I'm designing a specific template class Mystackt and I want to include entire class inside the public part of Mystackt as an iterator class MyIterator{}; 
I wrote all of this stuff in my header file MyTemplate.h
so briefly it will appear as following

```
template <class Type> /* that's in file **MyTemplate.h** */
class MyStackt
{
friend somefunction (int,string,bool);
public:

class iterator
{
public:
iterator();
void somefunc(param1,param2.....);
void otherfunc(...);
private:
Type* ptr;
};

int public_func_of_stackt(void);
void an-otherfunc(int,string,Type,...etc);
private:
int x;
string y;Type* val;
};
```

Now let's see he cpp file for this header MyTemplate.cpp
I can include the code for all member-functions of Mytemplate class without problems
for example :

```
template <class Type>
int MyStack<Type>::public_func_of_stackt(void)  /*this works perfect*/
{implementation goes here ...;}
```

but when i am trying to write the implementation of member-functions of entire class (iterator class) the problem starts

```
template <class Type>
bool MyStackt<Type>::iterator somefunc(param1,param2.....)
{ return current ==rhs.current; }
```

the question sirs is:
how I can include my code for the member-functions of class iterator inside the Mytemplate.cpp file ?? how should i write that using that external::entire or other specific notation ?
other question :
how can i write (in Mytemplate.cpp file) the implementation for a friend function of class MyStackt ??

update#1 : thank you Veritas

but i also need to know how to define some public function of class MyStackt
if that function is returning iterator type (so it is returning an object of the entire class)

the definition will look something like that

```
template <class Type>
iterator Stackt<Type>::begin()
{ return *this; }   /*this function did not work*/
```

maybe I need to use some specific notation 4 that ? what if I had a multiple nested classes 
waiting for the answer from experts 
thank you in advance !

Comment: If you want check my edit.

Comment: the template MyStackt class and the iterator class are big they have multiple constructors and functions
I moved some of my code into separated files so it will be more easy to maintain them later
functions of MyStackt which return an iterator object 
worked perfectly when i wrote their code inline-inside MyStackt scope- as you ment
but the problem came with this kind of code while i am trying to move this code to cpp and .h files 
    template <class Type>
    iterator Stackt<Type>::begin()
    { return *this; }
I tried the MyStackt::iterator notation , it doesn't work I get a syntax error

Comment: it's template<class Type>
MyStackt<Type>::iterator MyStackt<Type>::begin() {...}

Comment: but returning *this means that you return the MyStackt object which I don't think is what you want to do. If you meant to write "return this", it's still wrong since you want to return an iterator to the first element in the array that the MyStackt object handles, not a pointer to the actual MyStackt object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the scope resolution operator when defining somefunc. The definition should be:

```
template <class Type>
bool MyStackt<Type>::iterator::somefunc(param1,param2.....)
{ 
    return current == rhs.current; 
}
```

As for the friend function, you define it like any other global function.

To your edit:

The iterator class belongs to the MyStackt's scope so whenever you need to mention it out of MyStackt you need to use the scope operator. As for your question I am not sure what you are trying to do. *this returns the instantiated object which is of type MyStackt.

Also be careful!  If you want to seperate your definitions do so using .inl files or similar , not in a cpp file.